# Embedded DBs compatible with SQL Server Data

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, embedded-database

Working on a JAX-RS application which uses Microsoft-SQL-Server as a Database.
It does not use any ORM frameworks, just plain old JDBC.

Most of the application's operations involve store and retrieve data as XML into DB tables.

I have a use case where I have to run this application offline. So there wont be any connection available to DB SQL-Server.

Whilst looking into my options thought I would embed the DB and ship with the application EAR.

Looking into options I learned that, SQL-Server-Compact does not have a proper JDBC driver.

Is there any other In-Memory DB that could serve my purpose?

I want avoid any code changes like: changing the SQL queries (written specifically for Microsoft-SQL-Server).

Is there any solution which I can use and ship my application just by changing the DataSource to embedded DB?

*note: I could not find any useful post on stackoverflow for this query, If it's already been discussed. Please point me to the post and I will delete this duplicate question.*

Comment: Several Java embedded databases have compatibility modes (e.g., [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/compatibility-chapt.html#coc_compatibility_mssql), H2) so they can substitute for server-based databases during testing. Have you investigated any of those?

Comment: Hello thanks for the comment, I have not tried any of those yet. I fear they might not support the SQL Queries written specific to MS-SQL-Server. Specially the TransactSQL queries.